# How to change log level of dmesg programmatically?

Tags: c, debugging, kernel

I want to change the mask priority of dmesg by which i want to print only those messages whose priority is highest. So how to change these priority programmatically?

`Like if printk priority is KERN_ALERT or less than this then no message will printed in dmesg or console. I want only KERN_EMERG messages in dmesg.`

1 solution i have is just edit the printk proc file like -

`echo 0 >/proc/sys/kernel/printk`

But i want a `Kernel Space` API to do this.

I have used `setlogmask` also,but it was not working.

`Is do_syslog works here ??`

If yes then how??

I am writting a prog file to do this,like i want to  change the log-level of dmesg through that proc file.So is there any idea to do this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

There are predefined macros available.

```
KERN_EMERG      high priority       low number
KERN_ALERT
KERN_CRIT
KERN_ERR
KERN_WARNING
KERN_NOTICE
KERN_INFO
KERN_DEBUG      lo priority     hi number
```

for example

`printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello Module... ");`

Refer [here](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing) for setting kernel log levels.

Comment: I am not asking about this,i want to filter the dmesg in which only KERN_WARN messages of printk will be shown only.

Comment: i already gone through that but it was not useful,i am writing a proc file so i want some functions to do that,some kernel API to change the log-level..